# "To each is specialty." I do not understand

Tags: reading

-"Write about what you know. To each is specialty*. It is important to stick to the themes defined in the additional charter of your site. Don't scatter on topics outside the scope and be faithful to the editorial line defined at the beginning" - *I read it in an article and I do not understand what does it mean. Can anybody explain ?

Comment: Could you proved the context of the quote? The full sentence or ones before or after would be helpful. I tried searching that phrase on Google and there were 0 exact matches

Comment: Shure -"Write about what you know. To each is specialty. It is important to stick to the themes defined in the additional charter of your site."

Comment: (You should add the quote to the question and not just in a comment) Where does this come from? my first thought is that it is a typo and meant to be "to each his specialty" , which is probably an unidiomatic way of say [to each his own](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+each+his+own), meaning the third definition they give: *One has the right to one's personal preference*.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer

Comment: Is there an 'a' before speciality or not? It affects the probable answer

Comment: No there is no an 'a' before speciality

Comment: Please, please, please ***link*** to the quote. It reads as though it's a not-particularly-good translation (perhaps from Russian). Also, the quote in the question title does not match the quote in the body of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't because of the article on a paper, I printed it.

Comment: It could be a simple misprint for "To each his specialty" (see the answer from Balaz2ta), but there's not really any way of knowing.

Comment: Ah, ok it makes sense, probably it is a misprint

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an attempt at referencing **"To Each his own"**

From Merriam-Webster:

> used to say that other people are free to like different things

In this case - it means you are free to write to what your specialty is.  This is how I would understand it, given the context.